# GET request with curl. No errors, but Content-Length equals 0

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, wget, libcurl

Simple GET request with curl returns empty body (Content-Length: 0):

```
curl -v https://www.flyorientthai.com/booking/en/index.php
```

On the other hand wget can handle that url just fine:

```
wget https://www.flyorientthai.com/booking/en/index.php
```

What's wrong with curl?

Comment: Maybe server requires certain HTTP headers that curl doesn't normally send but wget does

Comment: @MJafarMash you're absolutely right :) 'Connection: Keep-Alive' header was missing with curl request and turned out it was critical.

Comment: What kind of broken server is this. Keep-Alive is implicit with HTTP/1.1, so this header would be redundant. But yes, using `curl -v -H "Connection: keep-alive"` gives the expected response while without the header not.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out `'Connection: Keep-Alive'` header is required. It's added by default to request with wget but not with curl.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using "Copy as cURL" in the Chrome developer tools network tab to generate a curl command — one of the lines in the generated curl command is a header that looks something like...

```
-H 'If-None-Match: W/"18f6a6-6p8AL7X/p71IhN/WztZm60Aue4k"'
```

That causes the server to return an empty 304 response if nothing's changed. Just whip it out.

Answer (score -2):

Let's try "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodeds"